# What will the decline in steps taken become?

Tags: statistics

\begin{array}{c|c}
Date & Value \\
\hline
7/11/2013  & 880 \\
10/25/2013 & 810 \\
12/23/2013 & 392 \\
4/9/2014   & 689 \\
7/23/2014  & 720 \\
4/23/2015  & 420 \\
7/23/2015  & 480 \\
10/22/2015 & 434 \\
2/3/2016   & 476 \\
3/3/2016   & 236 \\
3/31/2016  & 320 \\
7/5/2016   & 342 \\
1/23/2017  & 152 \\
6/1/2017   & 161 \\
\end{array}
Is there a way to predict what the next step counts will be for the rest of the year, every 3 months?

Comment: You should re-format your data in a two-column table: date, value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalizing the date scale to days since 2013-07-01, and constructing the best linear fit you end up with the equation $$v = 777.93 - 0.4448d$$ with $v$ denoting value and $d$ -- offset in days. The quality of the fit is a decent $R^2 = 76.21\%$, here is the graph from Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would re-cast your time data as relative to the start (in your case, 7/11/2013), in days. Then plot the data up in Excel in an $xy$ scatterplot, and try to fit curves to it. Make sure you display the equation and the $R^2$ value. If the $R^2$ value is very close to $1$, you have a good fit. Then you can use the fitted curve to predict future values.